# Inno Setup OR NSIS Automatic Rollback on Error / Abort of Install

Tags: installation, inno-setup, nsis, rollback

Is there a integrated Rollback-Action in any of the Installer-systems mentioned above? I know it's available in Windows Installer, but it seems to be missing in any other system I looked into.

Is there any system like Windows Installer that actually supports automatic Rollbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS does not support this because a script could do anything (Call any Windows API, use NSIS plugins to perform advanced tasks etc) and it would be impossible to know what and how to roll-back. But if you code the uninstaller to handle half-baked installs, you execute the uninstaller.

Comment: thx for your answer, that was what I actually feared. As I'm comparing Setup Engines for a company that's not that much into installer-programming - they have more than enough work with there applications and hardware drivers - it seems that I can't suggest anything not related to Windows Installer at the moment.

Comment: Any idea on InnoSetup? As it's also completely script-based, I fear that there is also no rollback concept…

Comment: @MFH - InnoSetup is not 100% script based, but suffers the same problems.

Answer (score 2):

Innosetup does not do what I'd call a rollback.  Case I tested was installing a newer version of a file over an older file, when cancelled IS displayed a box saying 'rolling back changes' however the newer file was still present (old file gone).

Answer (score 0):

NSIS does not support automatic rollbacks, you have to code it yourself.

InnoSetup, however, does provide automatic rollback support.  Special care needs to be taken to invoke it if you are using special scripts or hooks, but a simple install will have it "for free."